# enterprise library logger

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

I have a BIG client-serve application that uses Enterprise Library v4.0

It uses the Enterprise Library logger each time when there is a new connection to the DB.
When I shut down the logger (by using comments or my on/off boolean in the web.config and app.config) batch operations (e.g. requesting 100 records) it takes about 6-7 seconds. When I put the logger on, it takes about 20 seconds.

My question is how exactly the Enterprise Library operates the logger, Is it by using threads or not? How exactly can I tell?

I'm asking this question because I would like to call the logger using threads but if the library already uses threads, it will not be successful. Also, is using threads preferable for this operation? Do you think I need to use other logger, e.g Log4Net and such?

Comment: I'm curious how many logging calls you are making that is apparently taking the 16 seconds.  Are those timings (14 seconds for logging) for one client or when many clients are all running? Also what trace listener are you using?

Comment: It's in development enviroment, possibly 10-15 concurrent connection... not something that would create performance issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Enterprise Library Logger handles requests synchronously so it is not spawning threads to process write requests.

If you want to see what threads are being created, then you can monitor the threads in Visual Studio while debugging.

Your application could always start a thread to log the information but I would be vigilant in determining if starting potentially a large number of short lived threads actually helps performance.

I would recommend profiling to determine what is taking all the time.

Comment: After profiling, and checking with our DBAs, we came to conclusion that it was all about indexes in the DB (we removed some of them and added other indexes). Also, we are using Log4Net today instead of the enterprise library. Now, login time takes 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise Library Logging Application Block is thread-safe.
If you want to see how the Logger operates, check out the [source code](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/5/B/A5BF3B05-CB8A-40FE-B3E0-93FA84136D2B/Enterprise%20Library%205.0%20-%20Source%20Code.msi).